# Geometric Distribution to Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose that I want to find the expectation of a random variable X^6 so E[X^6]. Where X is a geometric distribution~(p). Now this distribution is hard to calculate so I want to approximate X by a suitable Exponential Distribution. I know that for an Exponential Distribution with X~(i), E[X^k]= k!/(i)^k but how can I find i from p?

Comment: $\operatorname{Geometric}(p) \sim\lfloor \operatorname{Exp}(-\log(1-p)) \rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$, $k\geqslant1$ then the generating function of $X$ is 
\begin{align}
G(s) &= \mathbb E\left[s^X\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty s^kp(1-p)^{k-1}\\
&= ps\sum_{k=0}^\infty ((1-p)s)^k\\
&= \frac{ps}{1-(1-p)s}.
\end{align}
The series converges for $|s|<\frac1{1-p}$, so we may compute the $n^{th}$ moment of $X$ by $G^{(n)}(1)$. In particular,
$$
G^{(6)}(s) = \frac{720p (1-p)^5 }{(1-(1-p) s)^7},
$$
and hence
$$
\mathbb E[X^6] = G^{(6)}(1) = \frac{720 (1-p)^5}{p^6}.
$$
It can be shown by induction that in general,
$$
\mathbb E[X^n] = \frac{n!(1-p)^{n-1}}{p^n}.
$$